# Are new instances of BackgroundTasks created each time they are run?

Tags: windows-8

When a `BackgroundTask`'s `Run` method is called, can I ever rely on using state saved in the class's fields by previous calls to `Run`? If so, when?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this for a `TimeTrigger`-triggered background task, and a new instance was created each time it was triggered and run.